# How do i use conky in i3 to make a custom widget to show rss feeds

Tags: linux-mint, rss, conky, i3

I want to create a widget in my i3 desktop homescreen that shows rss feed. So far i have only been able to do it in the bar. I am thinking about trying conky and make it execute everytime i open i3.

What i am trying to do is to make a widget showing rss news feeds in my i3 homescreen.

I am not very familiar with the language conky uses. I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.